# How I can fix 'Could not load file or assembly 'Spss' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'?

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms, spss

1. Build .aspx form app
2. Publish in local folder the app
3. Copy all artifacts on IIS website

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzK0z.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open IIS Manager (via run you can type inetmgr)
2. Choose you app pool
3. Advance settings
4. Set 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' to True